# Assign same ranks to same scores in LinQ

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, rank

I am writing a LinQ query in MVC to return ranks of students based on their scores like so

```
// Merge the LB lists to get aggregated List, allot dummy rank(0)
var a = leaderboard.ToDictionary((kvp => kvp.Key),
(kvp => kvp.Value.leaderboard)).Values.SelectMany(x => x).GroupBy(student => student.stId).Select(
g => new Leaderboard { 
stId = g.Key, 
stName = g.Select(x => x.stName).First(), 
rank = 0, 
score = g.Select(x => x.score).Sum(), 
cName = g.Select(x => x.cName).First() 
});

// Arrange the records in descending order of scores for rank
lbList = a.ToList().OrderByDescending(q => q.score).ToList();
int rank = 1;
lbList = lbList.Select(c => { c.rank = rank++; return c; }).ToList();
```

But for the same scores, this returns different ranks. Seeing as score is the only parameter without a time component, how do I change this to return same ranks for same scores?

Comment: `SelectMany(x => x)`? What is the point of this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a distinct collection of scores in an ordered sequence then use the position of the current student's score in the collection as his rank:

```
var UniqueScores = a.OrderByDescending(x=>x.score).Select(x=>x.score).Distinct().ToArray;
lbList = lbList.Select(c => { c.rank = (UniqueScores.IndexOf(c.score) + 1); return c; }).ToList();
```

Comment: The matter is that if the three first student is scored 45,45,36 the third student will be ranked as 2. You should remove Distinct() to make it ok.

Comment: The requirement is ambiguous on this point. But what you say is fair.

Answer (score 0):

## Preamble

This code looks quite suspicious:

```
var a = leaderboard.ToDictionary((kvp => kvp.Key),
(kvp => kvp.Value.leaderboard)).Values.SelectMany(x => x).GroupBy(student => student.stId).Select(
g => new Leaderboard { 
stId = g.Key, 
stName = g.Select(x => x.stName).First(), 
rank = 0, 
score = g.Select(x => x.score).Sum(), 
cName = g.Select(x => x.cName).First() 
});
```

1. `SelectMany(x => x)`. What is the point of this? It just does nothing.
2. `g.Select(x => x.cName).First()`. It's not optimal and less readable than this: `g.First().cName`.
3. ToDictionary... Again, does nothing in your case since you end up using only `Values`.

So, I would rewrite it like this:

```
var a = leaderboard.
    Select(x => x.Value.leaderboard).
    GroupBy(student => student.stId).
    Select(
        g => new Leaderboard { 
            stId = g.Key, 
            stName = g.First().stName,
            rank = 0, 
            score = g.Sum(x => x.score),
            cName = g.First().cName});
```

## Ranking

One thing to consider. Your code ends with `ToList()`. If you want to have `List<>` as output, then simple for loop is the best solution in my opinion:

```
var lbList = a.OrderByDescending(x => x.score);
int rank = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < lbList.Count; ++i)
{
    if (i > 0 && lbList[i - 1].score != lbList[i].score)
        ++rank;
    lbList[i].rank = rank;
}
```

If you need to have `lbList` as `IEnumerable<>` then:

```
var lbList = a.
    GroupBy(q => q.score).
    OrderByDescending(g => g.Key).
    SelectMany(
        (group, index) => group.Select(s => {
            s.rank = index + 1;
            return s;
        });
```

Comment: Thanks! Let me get back on this

Comment: You know... I have just realized that I have understood your question wrong. So, ranking section of my answer is not correct now :) Give me some time to fix it

Comment: Here it is. Needs testing though :)